# Using AWS EMR To Update S3 Data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, amazon-emr, amazon-athena

I am putting parquet files into an S3 bucket and using Athena to query it. I'd like to make row-level changes to my data, but i'm trying to avoid pulling down gigabytes of parquet data, modifying, and reuploading.

I've been messing with EMR all morning, getting acquainted with the tools available, but none are jumping out as a solution.

Will any of the EMR tools give me the ability to execute an `UPDATE x SET foo = 'bar'` type query on my existing s3 parquet data?

Comment: Hi Micah, If your data is sitting in S3, you can not update the data using commands like 'UPDATE X ....'. You will need to regenerate the parquet file combining with current file and taking the latest version of the data based on your key.

Comment: @TanveerUddin If I convert the files to ORC, and set the Hive transaction manager to DbTxnManager, would that change anything?

Comment: Yes, to your question. Then you are moving away from your original question of data being stored in S3. Hive with transaction support has some requisites. So you need to create ACID table fulfilling all the criteria.